# Why won't npm package update to latest version?

Tags: npm

I have grunt-contrib-uglify installed at version 0.2.7. According to [the repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), the latest version is 0.5. I tried to update via:

```
npm update grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

but this installs version 0.2.7 again. Am I supposed to manually update the version number in package.json and only then run the above line?

---

Bonus question: Why didn't my npm update?

[image]

Comment: What does your package.json have to say about the package?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7",`. Am I supposed to manually update this number first?

Comment: How would you like to lock down the version? Any version, major or minor >= 0.2.7 or any version with major version 0 and >= 0.2.7 or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 0.5.x sounds about right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two obvious wildcards to use, `^` (hold major) or `~` (hold minor);

```
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.x",
```

will install any version 0.x.x version of the package greater or equal to 0.5.0, but hold off on updating to version 1.x.x. This will allow update to pull the newest 0.x.x package.

```
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.x",
```

will install any 0.5.x version, but keep off on 0.6.x. This will allow update to pull the latest 0.5.x package.

Comment: so how do i move the hold major? just delete it from the package.json and run the update?